# How to display table with text and images in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, image, html-table, jupyter-notebook, python-imaging-library

I would like to display image samples and some related textual information with them, in table.

Is it possible to do this in jupyter notebook?

I tried to mix `pandas` and `PIL`, but it didn't work:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {
    'band1': data.to_images(band_1[random_indices]),
    'band2': data.to_images(band_2[random_indices]),
    'is_iceberg': is_iceberg[random_indices]
    }
pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

output was

[image]

i.e. it displayed `__str__` of images, not images themselves.

How to overcome?

Answer (score 10):

How about this?

I'm sure that setting `escape` in `to_html` is somewhat of a security risk maybe but if you know the data and know where it is coming from it is hopefully not that bad. If you change `escape` to `True` it will not work because the html is escaped by pandas. And this sets the same image in every row but that can be easily adjusted.

```
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,2,3,4,5], "B":[10,20,30,40,50]})
data.loc[:,'img'] = '<img src="Pictures/Capture.PNG" alt="img">'
display(HTML(data.to_html(escape=False)))
```

[EDIT] A better alternative would be

```
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
from PIL import Image
import cStringIO
import base64
import pandas as pd

img = Image.open("Pictures/Capture.PNG")
img_buffer = cStringIO.StringIO()
img.save(img_buffer, format="PNG")
imgStr = base64.b64encode(img_buffer.getvalue())

data = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,2,3,4,5], "B":[10,20,30,40,50]})
data.loc[:,'img'] = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,{0:s}">'
html_all = data.to_html(escape=False).format(imgStr)
display(HTML(html_all))
```

[image]

Comment: I have to call decode for it to work. `imgStr = base64.b64encode(img_buffer.getvalue()).decode()`